# SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, how to update my rects with new Position's

Tags: c++, sdl-2

At time i do little 2d Cookie clicker to learn c++. 
And now i need make that little game resizeble.

I have test SDL_Window_RESIZABLE. I see all is now bigger if im do streetch the Window. Thats nice.

Now i need update all rects for the new position.

So that is my problem, any idea how to do that?

Thanks much for any help.

main.cpp

```
 int main(){ 
    using namespace SDLGamecore;
        using namespace graphics;
        using namespace player;

        SDL_Thread *thread;

        std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
        Window window("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

        int frames = 0;
        const int fps = 30;
        Uint32 start;

        CostList costList;
        costList.workerCost = 15;
        costList.workerCashAmount = 1;
        costList.workerFrameCounter = 200;

        Player player("Test");

        std::stringstream s;

        Rects rect;
        rect.addRectWithPicture(200, 200, 80, 80, true, "money", 1, IMG_Load("schwein.png"));
        rect.addRectWithColor(50, 300, 100, 50, true, "worker", 1, 208, 28, 28, 0);
        rect.addRectWithText(200, 0, 600, 200, false, "default", 1, 20, 50, 50, 0, TTF_OpenFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 200), "0", 0);
        rect.addRectWithText(0, 0, 200, 200, true, "worker", 1, 200, 255, 200, 0, TTF_OpenFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 100), "0", 1);

        std::string pName = player.getName();
        std::cout << pName << std::endl;

        // Simply create a thread
        /*thread = SDL_CreateThread(TestThread, "TestThread", NULL);

        if (NULL == thread) {
            printf("\nSDL_CreateThread failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }*/

        window.eventRunning = true;
        while (window.eventRunning)
        {
            start = SDL_GetTicks();
            //eventHandler handle the close (x) + Keyevents and types.
            window.eventHandler(rect.getRects().data(), rect.getRects().size(), rect.getRectsConfig().data(), player.getCurrentCash(), costList);

            //Eventhandler save the current clicks, add callback to player
            if(window.getCurrentClicks() > 0)
            {
                player.addCash(window.getCurrentClicks());
            }
            window.resetCurrentClicks();

            //Update Cash display
            s << player.getCurrentCash() << "$";
            rect.updateRectWithText(s.str().c_str(), 0);
            s.str("");
            s.clear();

            //Eventhandler save the current workers, add callback to player
            if (window.getCurrentWorkers() > 0)
            {
                player.subtractCash(window.getCurrentWorkers() + 15);
                player.addWorker(window.getCurrentWorkers());
            }
            window.resetCurrentWorkers();

            //Update Worker display
            s << player.getWorkers();
            rect.updateRectWithText(s.str().c_str(), 1);
            s.str("");
            s.clear();

            //workerDothis
            if (frames == costList.workerFrameCounter)
            {
                player.addCash(player.getWorkers() + costList.workerCashAmount);
                frames = 0;
            }
            frames++;

            //std::cout << "New worker value: " << player.getWorkers() << std::endl;
            window.update(rect.getRects().data(), rect.getRects().size(), rect.getRectsConfig().data());

            if (1000 / fps > SDL_GetTicks() - start)
                SDL_Delay(1000 / fps - (SDL_GetTicks() - start));
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

rects.h

```
namespace SDLGamecore { namespace graphics {


        class Rects
        {
            std::vector<SDL_Rect> rects;
            std::vector<SDL_RectsConfig> config;
        public:
            Rects(){}
            void addRectWithText(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool isClickeble, std::string clickType, int clickValue, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b, Uint8 a, TTF_Font* font, std::string text, int targetId);
            void addRectWithColor(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool isClickeble, std::string clickType, int clickValue, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b, Uint8 a);
            void addRectWithPicture(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool isClickeble, std::string clickType, int clickValue, SDL_Surface *image);
            void updateRectWithText(std::string text, int targetId);
            std::vector<SDL_Rect>& getRects() 
            { 
                return rects; 
            }
            std::vector<SDL_RectsConfig>& getRectsConfig()
            {
                return config;
            }
        };
    }}
```

Comment: SDL notifies you with `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` event. Code it question doesn't seem to handle that at all (probably is, but hidden on window somewhere). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The Problem is: The rects dosnt resize, so my click function dosnt work correctly after streecht the window.  My Picture are Streetch now i need update my rects for the new size. Then my update function works correctly after streech. Sry for my bad english :P

Comment: Of course it does not since there is no code to do so. Already told you how to figure out when you get a resize, catch that event and update your rectangles accordingly. Or apply scaling to pointer click event, depending on what you're trying to achieve.